# SAS: How to loop trough years between a start and an end year?

Tags: loops, sas, global-variables

I am looping trough dates easily with this piece of code :

```
data _null_;
do year = 2000 to 2020;
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%annual_function)(',year,')'));
  end;
run;
```

where annual_function is a macro that include multiple 'data' steps.
The code is working well.

Now for practical purpose I am trying to make it work with global variables. Say :

```
%let start_year = 2000;
%let end_year = 2020;
```

But somehow the years are not recognized when I try to use :

```
data _null_;
do year = &start_year to &end_year;
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%annual_function)(',year,')'));
  end;
run;
```

Is this a format problem (string versus number) ? or a deeper one ?

Comment: Call execute is delayed execution, so it depends on code you call. Dynamically it's correct to use *call symget*, but not just assignment. Taking into account "delayed execution", sometimes all code needs to be remastered in different way.

Comment: You are using `DEBUT_YEAR` in your global macro assignment outside data step, and `START_YEAR` in the data step.  wink, wink, SAS is not smart enough to know DEBUT is the same as START, so yes it's a deeper meta-ontological problem ;)

Comment: ah sorry this is not an exact copy paste as I translated the variable name to english. this is not the problem here.

Comment: Post some of the log.  The format is not the problem.  The macro symbol start_year contains the characters `2` `0` `0` `0`.  However, those characters in the context of source code in a DATA Step as a do loop initial value become interpreted as the number 2,000 when the step is compiled (and run)

Comment: Are you getting the error in the data step that is generating the CALL EXECUTE()? Or when the macro calls that are being generated run? Show the error from the log, in context.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears to be working in a simple case, so something else is going on.

```
%let start_year = 2000;
%let end_year = 2020; 

%macro annual_function(year);
  %put NOTE: &SYSMACRONAME. &=YEAR;
%mend;

data _null_;
do year = &start_year to &end_year;
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%annual_function)(',year,')'));
  end;
run;
```

will log

```
1228  run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1    + %annual_function(2000)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2000
2    + %annual_function(2001)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2001
3    + %annual_function(2002)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2002
4    + %annual_function(2003)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2003
5    + %annual_function(2004)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2004
6    + %annual_function(2005)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2005
7    + %annual_function(2006)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2006
8    + %annual_function(2007)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2007
9    + %annual_function(2008)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2008
10   + %annual_function(2009)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2009
11   + %annual_function(2010)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2010
12   + %annual_function(2011)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2011
13   + %annual_function(2012)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2012
14   + %annual_function(2013)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2013
15   + %annual_function(2014)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2014
16   + %annual_function(2015)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2015
17   + %annual_function(2016)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2016
18   + %annual_function(2017)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2017
19   + %annual_function(2018)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2018
20   + %annual_function(2019)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2019
21   + %annual_function(2020)
NOTE: ANNUAL_FUNCTION YEAR=2020
```